# How to display radio buttons of a sfWidgetFormChoice individually?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I'd like to render a symfony form this way:

[image: form with radio buttons]

My problem concerns the radio buttons widget: I don't know how to render each choice individually, in order to display other fields between those radio buttons.

Is there a way to achieve this with symfony forms?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Symfony makes this a little difficult to do. You'd like a `renderChoice( $value)` method that's callable from the view, but that would require changing or extending sfFormField.

Changing it isn't future proof, and extending it would also require you to change some symfony variable so the fields accessible in your view are instances of this new class. I don't know if that option exists.

Instead, I opted to extend sfWidgetFormSelectRadio into the following very simple class which extends `formatChoices`. It will check if you're asking for only one option. If you are, it renders that tag and returns it, otherwise it renders normally via `parent::`.

This lets you call from your view: `$form['field']->render(array('only_choice'=> $value))`
where `$value` is the index of the radio option you want to render:

```
<?php

/**
 * sfWidgetFormSelectRadioSingleable lets you render just one option at a time.
 *
 * @package    symfony
 * @subpackage widget
 * @author     Fabien Potencier <fabien.potencier@symfony-project.com>
 * @version    SVN: $Id: sfWidgetFormSelectRadio.class.php 27738 2010-02-08 15:07:33Z Kris.Wallsmith $
 */
class sfWidgetFormSelectRadioSingleable extends sfWidgetFormSelectRadio
{
  public function formatChoices($name, $value, $choices, $attributes)
  {
    $onlyChoice = (!empty($attributes['only_choice'])) ? $attributes['only_choice'] : false; unset($attributes['only_choice']);

    if($onlyChoice)
    {
      if(!isset($choices[$onlyChoice]))
          throw new Exception("Option '$onlyChoice' doesn't exist.");

      $key    = $onlyChoice;
      $option = $choices[$key];
      $baseAttributes = array(
        'name'  => substr($name, 0, -2),
        'type'  => 'radio',
        'value' => self::escapeOnce($key),
        'id'    => $id = $this->generateId($name, self::escapeOnce($key)),
      );

      if (strval($key) == strval($value === false ? 0 : $value))
      {
        $baseAttributes['checked'] = 'checked';
      }

      return $this->renderTag('input', array_merge($baseAttributes, $attributes));
    }
    else
    {
      return parent::formatChoices($name, $value, $choices, $attributes);
    }
  }
}
```

Awkward code, but easy enough to use in practice and it won't break in the future.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I also stored it as a Gist on GitHub for my own records https://gist.github.com/4165050

Comment: First of all, Thanks for sharing this. I know it's long time ago but here's what I found to be faulty. Maybe one will need it in the future.

If your radio options are 
e.g. `array(1=>"Yes", 0=>"No")`
the widget won't display correctly. Because $onlyChoice=... in the first line will evaluate to "false" for the option `0=>"No"`. This will then force the execution of the else path and will display 2 radio buttons for option 0 instead of one. Finally you'll have 3 Radio buttons instead of 2.
For me this change works: `if(!is_null($onlyChoice) && is_int(intval($onlyChoice)))`

Answer (score 1):

The standard widgets are not going to allow you to inject another field in between elements of one field; see `sfWidgetFormSelectRadio::formatChoices()` for why this is. My first reaction is to extend sfWidgetFormSelectRadio, including a `renderChoice( $value )` method.

Answer (score 0):

How about defining separate [`sfWidgetFormSelectRadio`](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfWidgetFormSelectRadio) widgets with the same name and different values?

Comment: Hum, you're right, it may work, but it's not a smart solution to me.